# Prove that uniformly random states have moments ${\bf E}_\psi|\langle x|\psi\rangle|^{2t}\sim1/\binom d t$

Tags: quantum-state, random-quantum-circuit, haar-distribution

Im looking for the moments of Haar random states. Is it true that
$\textbf{E}_{\psi\sim \text{Haar}}|\langle x| \psi\rangle|^{2t}\sim \frac{1}{\binom{d}{t}}?$  How does one prove this?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14218/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14783/55

Answer (score 3):

The factor in your claim is wrong. It should be $\binom{d+t-1}{t}^{-1}$. The correct claim follows from the identity
$$
 \int |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|^{\otimes t} d\psi = \binom{d+t-1}{t}^{-1} P_{\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)} \,,
$$
where $P_{\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)}$ is the projector onto the symmetric subspace in $(\mathbb C^d)^{\otimes t}$. Indeed, setting $D_t:=\binom{d+t-1}{t}$, we find
$$
 \int |\langle x|\psi\rangle|^{2t} d\psi 
 =
 D_t^{-1} \langle x|^{\otimes t} P_{\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)}|x\rangle^{\otimes t} 
 =
 D_t^{-1} \langle x|x\rangle^{t} 
 =
 D_t^{-1}.
$$

So why does the first formula hold? Observe that the integral $A:= \int |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|^{\otimes t} d\psi$ is symmetric under permutation of tensor factors and hence represents an operator on the symmetric subspace $\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)$ of dimension $D_t=\binom{d+t-1}{t}$.
Moreover, $A$ commutes with any $U^{\otimes t}$ where $U\in U(d)$. Now, since the symmetric subspace is irreducible under the action of $U^{\otimes t}$, Schur's lemma says that the operator $A$ has to proportional to the identity on $\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)$, i.e. to the projector $P_{\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)}$.
Since $A$ has trace one, we find that the correct proportionality factor is $\mathrm{tr}(P_{\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)})^{-1} = D_t^{-1}$:
$$
 \int |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|^{\otimes t} d\psi = D_t^{-1} P_{\mathrm{Sym}^t(\mathbb C^d)} \,.
$$

**Remark**: More general Haar integrals can be computed similarly, c.f. [my answer here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23846/2305)